# create XML from text and element offsets in scala

Tags: xml, scala, text, offset

I need to create an XML document from a piece of plain text and the begin and end offsets of each XML element that should be inserted. Here are a few test cases I'd like it to pass:

```
val text = "The dog chased the cat."
val spans = Seq(
    (0, 23, <xml/>),
    (4, 22, <phrase/>),
    (4, 7, <token/>))
val expected = <xml>The <phrase><token>dog</token> chased the cat</phrase>.</xml>
assert(expected === spansToXML(text, spans))

val text = "aabbccdd"
val spans = Seq(
    (0, 8, <xml x="1"/>),
    (0, 4, <ab y="foo"/>),
    (4, 8, <cd z="42>3"/>))
val expected = <xml x="1"><ab y="foo">aabb</ab><cd z="42>3">ccdd</cd></xml>
assert(expected === spansToXML(text, spans))

val spans = Seq(
    (0, 1, <a/>),
    (0, 0, <b/>),
    (0, 0, <c/>),
    (1, 1, <d/>),
    (1, 1, <e/>))
assert(<a><b/><c/> <d/><e/></a> === spansToXML(" ", spans))
```

My partial solution (see my answer below) works by string concatenation and `XML.loadString`. That seems hacky, and I'm also not 100% sure this solution works correctly in all the corner cases...

Any better solutions? (For what it's worth, I'd be happy to switch to [anti-xml](http://anti-xml.org/) if that would make this task easier.)

**Updated 10 Aug 2011** to add more test cases and provide a cleaner specification.

Comment: You do realize this can produce invalid XML, don't you? It can produce non-matching tags.

Comment: I suspected as much, hence the comment "I'm also not 100% sure it works correctly in all the corner cases...". Do you know how to fix it? Or can you at least provide some test cases that show how it fails?

Comment: You'd want to build spans as a tree structure, with each node having start/end positions inside the range of the parent node.  That would also simplify the problem of building inner nodes first!

Comment: I don't really have a choice about how the spans come in. Or are you suggesting to first translate the list of spans into a tree structure and then build the XML from that?

Comment: I think that's what he's suggesting, but I also think that actually building such a tree is overkill (see my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the bounty you put forward, I studied your problem for some time and came up with the following solution, which succeeds on all your testcases.
I would really like getting my answer accepted - please tell me if there's anything wrong with my solution.

Some comments:
I left the commented out print statement inside, if you wanna figure what's going on during execution.
In addition to your specification, I do preserve their existing children (if any) - there's a comment where this is done.

I do not build the XML nodes manually, I modify the ones passed in. To avoid splitting the opening and closing tag, I had to change the algorithm quite a lot, but the idea of sorting spans by `begin` and `-end` comes from your solution.

The code is somewhat advanced Scala, especially when I build the different `Orderings` I need. I did simplify it somewhat from the first version I got.

I avoided creating a tree representing the intervals, by using a `SortedMap`, and filtering the intervals after extraction. This choice is somewhat suboptimal; however, I heard that there are "better" data structures for representing nested intervals, like interval trees (they are studied in computational geometry), but they're quite complex to implement, and I don't think it's needed here.

```
/**
 * User: pgiarrusso
 * Date: 12/8/2011
 */

import collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import collection.SortedMap
import scala.xml._

object SpansToXmlTest {
    def spansToXML(text: String, spans: Seq[(Int, Int, Elem)]) = {
        val intOrdering = implicitly[Ordering[Int]] // Retrieves the standard ordering on Ints.

        // Sort spans decreasingly on begin and increasingly on end and their label - this processes spans outwards.
        // The sorting on labels matches the given examples.
        val spanOrder = Ordering.Tuple3(intOrdering.reverse, intOrdering, Ordering.by((_: Elem).label))

        //Same sorting, excluding labels.
        val intervalOrder = Ordering.Tuple2(intOrdering.reverse, intOrdering)
        //Map intervals of the source string to the sequence of nodes which match them - it is a sequence because
        //multiple spans for the same interval are allowed.
        var intervalMap = SortedMap[(Int, Int), Seq[Node]]()(intervalOrder)

        for ((start, end, elem) <- spans.sorted(spanOrder)) {
            //Only nested intervals. Interval nesting is a partial order, therefore we cannot use the filter function as an ordering for intervalMap, even if it would be nice.
            val nestedIntervalsMap = intervalMap.until((start, end)).filter(_ match {
                case ((intStart, intEnd), _) => start <= intStart && intEnd <= end
            })
            //println("intervalMap: " + intervalMap)
            //println("beforeMap: " + nestedIntervalsMap)

            //We call sorted to use a standard ordering this time.
            val before = nestedIntervalsMap.keys.toSeq.sorted

            // text.slice(start, end) must be split into fragments, some of which are represented by text node, some by
            // already computed xml nodes.
            val intervals = start +: (for {
                (intStart, intEnd) <- before
                boundary <- Seq(intStart, intEnd)
            } yield boundary) :+ end

            var xmlChildren = ArrayBuffer[Node]()
            var useXmlNode = false

            for (interv <- intervals.sliding(2)) {
                val intervStart = interv(0)
                val intervEnd = interv(1)
                xmlChildren.++=(
                    if (useXmlNode)
                        intervalMap((intervStart, intervEnd)) //Precomputed nodes
                    else
                        Seq(Text(text.slice(intervStart, intervEnd))))
                useXmlNode = !useXmlNode //The next interval will be of the opposite kind.
            }
            //Remove intervals that we just processed
            intervalMap = intervalMap -- before

            // By using elem.child, you also preserve existing xml children. "elem.child ++" can be also commented out.
            var tree = elem.copy(child = elem.child ++ xmlChildren)
            intervalMap += (start, end) -> (intervalMap.getOrElse((start, end), Seq.empty) :+ tree)
            //println(tree)
        }
        intervalMap((0, text.length)).head
    }

    def test(text: String, spans: Seq[(Int, Int, Elem)], expected: Node) {
        val res = spansToXML(text, spans)
        print("Text: \"%s\", expected:\n%s\nResult:\n%s\n\n" format (text, expected, res))
        assert(expected == res)
    }
    def test1() =
        test(
            text = "The dog chased the cat.",
            spans = Seq(
                (0, 23, <xml/>),
                (4, 22, <phrase/>),
                (4, 7, <token/>)),
            expected = <xml>The <phrase><token>dog</token> chased the cat</phrase>.</xml>
        )

    def test2() =
        test(
            text = "aabbccdd",
            spans = Seq(
                (0, 8, <xml x="1"/>),
                (0, 4, <ab y="foo"/>),
                (4, 8, <cd z="42>3"/>)),
            expected = <xml x="1"><ab y="foo">aabb</ab><cd z="42>3">ccdd</cd></xml>
        )

    def test3() =
        test(
            text = " ",
            spans = Seq(
                (0, 1, <a/>),
                (0, 0, <b/>),
                (0, 0, <c/>),
                (1, 1, <d/>),
                (1, 1, <e/>)),
            expected = <a><b/><c/> <d/><e/></a>
        )

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        test1()
        test2()
        test3()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just discovered from david.rosell code (and verified) that `implicitly[Ordering[Int]]` can be replaced (specifically for `Ordering`) by `Ordering[Int]`.

Comment: This is a pretty cool solution! It took me a little while to wrap my head around it, but this is exactly the kind of thing I was hoping for - you create the nodes directly, not the `XML.loadString` kind of hack I was doing.

For anyone else reading this solution, the key is to realize that, due to the interval sorting order, all elements within a span are completely processed before the span itself is processed. Thus, all the main for-loop needs to do is take the nested elements, interleave them with the appropriate text, add them to the element, and push the element back on the map.

Comment: Oh, the one thing "wrong" with your solution (well, the one thing I didn't specify well) was that I didn't want to sort based on the element name - instead you should just use the elements in the order they were passed in. That's pretty easy to accomplish by just modifying your `spanOrder` definition.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for accepting it anyway, that's great. I think I took the by-name sorting from your code, even if it wasn't clear whether it was intended. But I'm also happy that my code was easy to understand and modify for you :-).

Answer (score 2):

This was fun!

I took an approche similar to Steve's. 
By sorting up the element's in "start tags" and "end tags", then calculating where to put them.

I shamelessly stole the test's from Blaisorblade, and added a couple of more that helped me developing the code.

EDITED on 2011-08-14

I was unhappy how the empty tag where inserted in test-5. However this placement where a consequence of how test-3 where formulated

- even if the empty tags (c,d) where after the spanning tag (a) in the spans list and the c,d-tags has insertion points same as the end tag of a, the c,d tag goes inside a.
  This make it hard to place empty tags between spanning tags which could be useful.

So, I changed some test's around a little and provided an alternative solution.

In the alternative solution I start up in the same way, but have 3 separate lists, start, empty and closing tags. And instead of only sorting I have a third step where the empty tags are  placed into the tag list.

**First solution:**

```
import xml.{XML, Elem, Node}
import annotation.tailrec

object SpanToXml {
    def spansToXML(text: String, spans: Seq[(Int, Int, Elem)]): Node = {
        // Create a Seq of elements, sorted by where it should be inserted
        //  differentiate start tags ('s) and empty tags ('e)
        val startElms = spans sorted Ordering[Int].on[(Int, _, _)](_._1) map {
            case e if e._1 != e._2 => (e._1, e._3, 's)
            case e => (e._1, e._3, 'e)
        }
        //Create a Seq of closing tags ('c), sorted by where they should be inserted
        // filter out all empty tags
        val endElms = spans.reverse.sorted(Ordering[Int].on[(_, Int, _)](_._2))
            .filter(e => e._1 != e._2)
            .map(e => (e._2, e._3, 'c))

        //Combine the Seq's and sort by insertion point
        val elms = startElms ++ endElms sorted Ordering[Int].on[(Int, _, _)](_._1)
        //The sorting need to be refined
        // - end tag's need to come before start tag's if the insertion point is thesame
        val sorted = elms.sortWith((a, b) => a._1 == b._1 && a._3 == 'c && b._3 == 's )

        //Adjust the insertion point to what it should be in the final string
        // then insert the tags into the text by folding left
        // - there are different rules depending on start, empty or close
        val txt = adjustInset(sorted).foldLeft(text)((tx, e) => {
            val s = tx.splitAt(e._1)
            e match {
                case (_, elem, 's) => s._1 + "<" + elem.label + elem.attributes + ">" + s._2
                case (_, elem, 'e) => s._1 + "<" + elem.label + elem.attributes + "/>" + s._2
                case (_, elem, 'c) => s._1 + "</" + elem.label + ">" + s._2
            }
        })
        //Sanity check
        //println(txt)

        //Convert to XML
        XML.loadString(txt)
    }

    def adjustInset(elems: Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)]): Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)] = {
        @tailrec
        def adjIns(elems: Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)], tmp: Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)]): Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)] =
            elems match {
                case t :: Nil => tmp :+ t
                case t :: ts => {
                    //calculate offset due to current element
                    val offset = t match {
                        case (_, e, 's) => e.label.size + e.attributes.toString.size + 2
                        case (_, e, 'e) => e.label.size + e.attributes.toString.size + 3
                        case (_, e, 'c) => e.label.size + 3
                    }
                    //add offset to all elm's in tail, and recurse
                    adjIns(ts.map(e => (e._1 + offset, e._2, e._3)), tmp :+ t)
                }
            }

            adjIns(elems, Nil)
    }

    def test(text: String, spans: Seq[(Int, Int, Elem)], expected: Node) {
        val res = spansToXML(text, spans)
        print("Text: \"%s\", expected:\n%s\nResult:\n%s\n\n" format (text, expected, res))
        assert(expected == res)
    }

    def test1() =
        test(
            text = "The dog chased the cat.",
            spans = Seq(
                (0, 23, <xml/>),
                (4, 22, <phrase/>),
                (4, 7, <token/>)),
            expected = <xml>The <phrase><token>dog</token> chased the cat</phrase>.</xml>
        )

    def test2() =
        test(
            text = "aabbccdd",
            spans = Seq(
                (0, 8, <xml x="1"/>),
                (0, 4, <ab y="foo"/>),
                (4, 8, <cd z="42>3"/>)),
            expected = <xml x="1"><ab y="foo">aabb</ab><cd z="42>3">ccdd</cd></xml>
        )

    def test3() =
        test(
            text = " ",
            spans = Seq(
                (0, 1, <a/>),
                (0, 0, <b/>),
                (0, 0, <c/>),
                (1, 1, <d/>),
                (1, 1, <e/>)),
            expected = <a><b/><c/> <d/><e/></a>
        )

    def test4() =
        test(
            text = "aabbccdd",
            spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                        (0, 4, <ab/>),
                        (4, 8, <cd/>),
                        (4, 6, <ok/>)),
            expected = <xml><ab>aabb</ab><cd><ok>cc</ok>dd</cd></xml>
        )

    def test5() =
        test(
            text = "aabbccdd",
            spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                        (0, 4, <ab/>),
                        (2, 4, <b/>),
                        (4, 4, <empty/>),
                        (4, 8, <cd/>),
                        (4, 6, <ok/>)),
            expected = <xml><ab>aa<b>bb<empty/></b></ab><cd><ok>cc</ok>dd</cd></xml>
        )

    def test6() =
        test(
            text = "aabbccdd",
            spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                        (0, 4, <ab/>),
                        (2, 4, <b/>),
                        (2, 4, <c/>),
                        (3, 4, <d/>),
                        (4, 8, <cd/>),
                        (4, 6, <ok/>)),
            expected = <xml><ab>aa<b><c>b<d>b</d></c></b></ab><cd><ok>cc</ok>dd</cd></xml>
        )

    def test7() =
        test(
            text = "aabbccdd",
            spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                        (0, 4, <ab a="a" b="b"/>),
                        (4, 8, <cd c="c" d="d"/>)),
            expected = <xml><ab a="a" b="b">aabb</ab><cd c="c" d="d">ccdd</cd></xml>
        )

    def invalidSpans() = {
        val text = "aabbccdd"
        val spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                        (0, 4, <ab/>),
                        (4, 6, <err/>),
                        (4, 8, <cd/>))
        try {
            val res = spansToXML(text, spans)
            assert(false)
        } catch {
            case e => {
                println("This generate invalid XML:")
                println("<xml><ab>aabb</ab><err><cd>cc</err>dd</cd></xml>")
                println(e.getMessage)
            }
        }
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        test1()
        test2()
        test3()
        test4()
        test5()
        test6()
        test7()
        invalidSpans()
    }
}

SpanToXml.main(Array())
```

**Alternative solution:**

```
import xml.{XML, Elem, Node}
import annotation.tailrec

object SpanToXmlAlt {
    def spansToXML(text: String, spans: Seq[(Int, Int, Elem)]): Node = {
        // Create a Seq of start tags, sorted by where it should be inserted
        // filter out all empty tags
        val startElms = spans.sorted(Ordering[Int].on[(Int, _, _)](_._1))
            .filterNot(e => e._1 == e._2)
            .map(e => (e._1, e._3, 's))
        //Create a Seq of closing tags, sorted by where they should be inserted
        // filter out all empty tags
        val endElms = spans.reverse.sorted(Ordering[Int].on[(_, Int, _)](_._2))
            .filterNot(e => e._1 == e._2)
            .map(e => (e._2, e._3, 'c))

        //Create a Seq of empty tags, sorted by where they should be inserted
        val emptyElms = spans.sorted(Ordering[Int].on[(Int, _, _)](_._1))
            .filter(e => e._1 == e._2)
            .map(e => (e._1, e._3, 'e))

        //Combine the Seq's and sort by insertion point
        val elms = startElms ++ endElms sorted Ordering[Int].on[(Int, _, _)](_._1)
        //The sorting need to be refined
        // - end tag's need to come before start tag's if the insertion point is the same
        val sorted = elms.sortWith((a, b) => a._1 == b._1 && a._3 == 'c && b._3 == 's )

        //Insert empty tags
        val allSorted = insertEmpyt(spans, sorted, emptyElms) sorted Ordering[Int].on[(Int, _, _)](_._1)
        //Adjust the insertion point to what it should be in the final string
        // then insert the tags into the text by folding left
        // - there are different rules depending on start, empty or close
        val str = adjustInset(allSorted).foldLeft(text)((tx, e) => {
            val s = tx.splitAt(e._1)
            e match {
                case (_, elem, 's) => s._1 + "<" + elem.label + elem.attributes + ">" + s._2
                case (_, elem, 'e) => s._1 + "<" + elem.label + elem.attributes + "/>" + s._2
                case (_, elem, 'c) => s._1 + "</" + elem.label + ">" + s._2
            }
        })
        //Sanity check
        //println(str)
        //Convert to XML
        XML.loadString(str)
    }

    def insertEmpyt(spans: Seq[(Int, Int, Elem)],
        sorted: Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)],
        emptys: Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)]): Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)] = {

        //Find all tags that should be before the empty tag
        @tailrec
        def afterSpan(empty: (Int, Elem, Symbol),
            spans: Seq[(Int, Int, Elem)],
            after: Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)]): Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)] = {
            var result = after
            spans match {
                case t :: _ if t._1 == empty._1 && t._2 == empty._1 && t._3 == empty._2 => after //break
                case t :: ts if t._1 == t._2 => afterSpan(empty, ts, after :+ (t._1, t._3, 'e))
                case t :: ts => {
                    if (t._1 <= empty._1) result = result :+ (t._1, t._3, 's)
                    if (t._2 <= empty._1) result = result :+ (t._2, t._3, 'c)
                    afterSpan(empty, ts, result)
                }
            }
        }

        //For each empty tag, insert it in the sorted list
        var result = sorted
        emptys.foreach(e => {
            val afterSpans = afterSpan(e, spans, Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)]())
            var emptyInserted = false
            result = result.foldLeft(Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)]())((res, s) => {
                if (afterSpans.contains(s) || emptyInserted) {
                    res :+ s
                } else {
                    emptyInserted = true
                    res :+ e :+ s
                }
            })
        })
        result
    }

    def adjustInset(elems: Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)]): Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)] = {
        @tailrec
        def adjIns(elems: Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)], tmp: Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)]): Seq[(Int, Elem, Symbol)] =
            elems match {
                case t :: Nil => tmp :+ t
                case t :: ts => {
                    //calculate offset due to current element
                    val offset = t match {
                        case (_, e, 's) => e.label.size + e.attributes.toString.size + 2
                        case (_, e, 'e) => e.label.size + e.attributes.toString.size + 3
                        case (_, e, 'c) => e.label.size + 3
                    }
                    //add offset to all elm's in tail, and recurse
                    adjIns(ts.map(e => (e._1 + offset, e._2, e._3)), tmp :+ t)
                }
            }

            adjIns(elems, Nil)
    }

    def test(text: String, spans: Seq[(Int, Int, Elem)], expected: Node) {
        val res = spansToXML(text, spans)
        print("Text: \"%s\", expected:\n%s\nResult:\n%s\n\n" format (text, expected, res))
        assert(expected == res)
    }

    def test1() =
        test(
            text = "The dog chased the cat.",
            spans = Seq(
                (0, 23, <xml/>),
                (4, 22, <phrase/>),
                (4, 7, <token/>)),
            expected = <xml>The <phrase><token>dog</token> chased the cat</phrase>.</xml>
        )

    def test2() =
        test(
            text = "aabbccdd",
            spans = Seq(
                (0, 8, <xml x="1"/>),
                (0, 4, <ab y="foo"/>),
                (4, 8, <cd z="42>3"/>)),
            expected = <xml x="1"><ab y="foo">aabb</ab><cd z="42>3">ccdd</cd></xml>
        )

    def test3alt() =
        test(
            text = "  ",
            spans = Seq(
                (0, 2, <a/>),
                (0, 0, <b/>),
                (0, 0, <c/>),
                (1, 1, <d/>),
                (1, 1, <e/>)),
            expected = <a><b/><c/> <d/><e/> </a>
        )

    def test4() =
        test(
            text = "aabbccdd",
            spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                        (0, 4, <ab/>),
                        (4, 8, <cd/>),
                        (4, 6, <ok/>)),
            expected = <xml><ab>aabb</ab><cd><ok>cc</ok>dd</cd></xml>
        )

    def test5alt() =
        test(
            text = "aabbccdd",
            spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                        (0, 4, <ab/>),
                        (2, 4, <b/>),
                        (4, 4, <empty/>),
                        (4, 8, <cd/>),
                        (4, 6, <ok/>)),
            expected = <xml><ab>aa<b>bb</b></ab><empty/><cd><ok>cc</ok>dd</cd></xml>
        )

    def test5b() =
        test(
            text = "aabbccdd",
            spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                        (0, 4, <ab/>),
                        (2, 2, <empty1/>),
                        (4, 4, <empty2/>),
                        (2, 4, <b/>),
                        (2, 2, <empty3/>),
                        (4, 4, <empty4/>),
                        (4, 8, <cd/>),
                        (4, 6, <ok/>)),
            expected = <xml><ab>aa<empty1/><b><empty3/>bb<empty2/></b></ab><empty4/><cd><ok>cc</ok>dd</cd></xml>
        )

    def test6() =
        test(
            text = "aabbccdd",
            spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                        (0, 4, <ab/>),
                        (2, 4, <b/>),
                        (2, 4, <c/>),
                        (3, 4, <d/>),
                        (4, 8, <cd/>),
                        (4, 6, <ok/>)),
            expected = <xml><ab>aa<b><c>b<d>b</d></c></b></ab><cd><ok>cc</ok>dd</cd></xml>
        )

    def test7() =
        test(
            text = "aabbccdd",
            spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                        (0, 4, <ab a="a" b="b"/>),
                        (4, 8, <cd c="c" d="d"/>)),
            expected = <xml><ab a="a" b="b">aabb</ab><cd c="c" d="d">ccdd</cd></xml>
        )

    def failedSpans() = {
        val text = "aabbccdd"
        val spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                        (0, 4, <ab/>),
                        (4, 6, <err/>),
                        (4, 8, <cd/>))
        try {
            val res = spansToXML(text, spans)
            assert(false)
        } catch {
            case e => {
                println("This generate invalid XML:")
                println("<xml><ab>aabb</ab><err><cd>cc</err>dd</cd></xml>")
                println(e.getMessage)
            }
        }

    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        test1()
        test2()
        test3alt()
        test4()
        test5alt()
        test5b()
        test6()
        test7()
        failedSpans()
    }
}

SpanToXmlAlt.main(Array())
```

Comment: What's the advantage of manipulating XML tags as text, risking to produce non-well-formed XML if there's a code bug?

Comment: When using this strategy to convert text to xml, it is quite easy to declare spans that will produce invalid xml - nesting "start tags"-"end tags" or not having a single parent tag.

Comment: I believe its easier to divide the problem. First: sorting where the tags should be placed and Second: producing the xml. When using this strategy to convert text to xml, it is quite easy to declare spans that will produce invalid xml - nesting "start tags"-"end tags" or not having a single parent tag. So, you have to be careful when declaring the list of spans, and if the spans are declared wrong you get an error instead of strange xml. You also have to be aware that not every arbitrary valid xml can be produced in this way - however, it could be good enough depending on your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is a recursive one. I sort the input `Seq` acording to my needs and convert it to a `List`. After that it's basic pattern matching according to the specifications needs. The biggest drawback to my solution is that, while `.toString` produces the same Strings in the test method `==` doesn't yield true.

```scala
import scala.xml.{NodeSeq, Elem, Text}

object SpansToXml {
  type NodeSpan = (Int, Int, Elem)

  def adjustIndices(offset: Int, spans: List[NodeSpan]) = spans.map {
    case (spanStart, spanEnd, spanNode) => (spanStart - offset, spanEnd - offset, spanNode)
  }

  def sortedSpansToXml(text: String, spans: List[NodeSpan]): NodeSeq = {
    spans match {
      // current span starts and ends at index 0, thus no inner text exists
      case (0, 0, node) :: rest => node +: sortedSpansToXml(text, rest)

      // current span starts at index 0 and ends somewhere greater than 0
      case (0, end, node) :: rest =>
        // partition the text and the remaining spans in inner and outer and process both independently
        val (innerSpans, outerSpans) = rest.partition {
          case (spanStart, spanEnd, spanNode) => spanStart <= end && spanEnd <= end
        }
        val (innerText, outerText) = text.splitAt(end)

        // prepend the generated node to the outer xml
        node.copy(child = node.child ++ sortedSpansToXml(innerText, innerSpans)) +: sortedSpansToXml(outerText, adjustIndices(end, outerSpans))

      // current span has starts at an index larger than 0, convert text prefix to text node
      case (start, end, node) :: rest =>
        val (pre, spanned) = text.splitAt(start)
        Text(pre) +: sortedSpansToXml(spanned, adjustIndices(start, spans))

      // all spans consumed: we can just return the text as node
      case Nil =>
        Text(text)
    }
  }

  def spansToXml(xmlText: String, nodeSpans: Seq[NodeSpan]) = {
    val sortedSpans = nodeSpans.toList.sortBy {
      case (start, end, _) => (start, -end)
    }
    sortedSpansToXml(xmlText, sortedSpans)
  }

  // test code stolen from Blaisorblade and david.rosell

  def test(text: String, spans: Seq[(Int, Int, Elem)], expected: NodeSeq) {
    val res = spansToXml(text, spans)
    print("Text: \"%s\", expected:\n%s\nResult:\n%s\n\n" format (text, expected, res))
    // Had to resort on to string here.
    assert(expected.toString == res.toString)
  }

  def test1() =
        test(
            text = "The dog chased the cat.",
            spans = Seq((0, 23, <xml/>),(4, 22, <phrase/>),(4, 7, <token/>)),
            expected = <xml>The <phrase><token>dog</token> chased the cat</phrase>.</xml>
        )

  def test2() =
        test(
            text = "aabbccdd",
            spans = Seq(
                (0, 8, <xml x="1"/>),
                (0, 4, <ab y="foo"/>),
                (4, 8, <cd z="42>3"/>)),
            expected = <xml x="1"><ab y="foo">aabb</ab><cd z="42>3">ccdd</cd></xml>
        )

  def test3() =
        test(
            text = " ",
            spans = Seq(
                (0, 1, <a/>),
                (0, 0, <b/>),
                (0, 0, <c/>),
                (1, 1, <d/>),
                (1, 1, <e/>)),
            expected = <a><b/><c/> <d/><e/></a>
        )

  def test4() =
      test(
          text = "aabbccdd",
          spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                      (0, 4, <ab/>),
                      (4, 8, <cd/>),
                      (4, 6, <ok/>)),
          expected = <xml><ab>aabb</ab><cd><ok>cc</ok>dd</cd></xml>
      )

  def test5() =
      test(
          text = "aabbccdd",
          spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                      (0, 4, <ab/>),
                      (2, 4, <b/>),
                      (4, 4, <empty/>),
                      (4, 8, <cd/>),
                      (4, 6, <ok/>)),
          expected = <xml><ab>aa<b>bb<empty/></b></ab><cd><ok>cc</ok>dd</cd></xml>
      )

  def test6() =
      test(
          text = "aabbccdd",
          spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                      (0, 4, <ab/>),
                      (2, 4, <b/>),
                      (2, 4, <c/>),
                      (3, 4, <d/>),
                      (4, 8, <cd/>),
                      (4, 6, <ok/>)),
          expected = <xml><ab>aa<b><c>b<d>b</d></c></b></ab><cd><ok>cc</ok>dd</cd></xml>
      )

  def test7() =
      test(
          text = "aabbccdd",
          spans = Seq((0, 8, <xml/>),
                      (0, 4, <ab a="a" b="b"/>),
                      (4, 8, <cd c="c" d="d"/>)),
          expected = <xml><ab a="a" b="b">aabb</ab><cd c="c" d="d">ccdd</cd></xml>
      )

}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution too other than that equality issue. I'm guessing this solution creates a few more `Text` nodes or something like that, and so the XML compares unequal even though the normalized forms would be the same...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily creates XML nodes dynamically:

```
scala> import scala.xml._
import scala.xml._

scala> Elem(null, "AAA",xml.Null,xml.TopScope, Array[Node]():_*)
res2: scala.xml.Elem = <AAA></AAA>
```

Here is the [Elem.apply](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/scala/xml/Elem%24.html) signature `def apply (prefix: String, label: String, attributes: MetaData, scope: NamespaceBinding, child: Node*) : Elem`

The only problem I see with this approach is that you will need to build the inner nodes first.

Something to make it easier:

```
scala> def elem(name:String, children:Node*) = Elem(null, name ,xml.Null,xml.TopScope, children:_*); def elem(name:String):Elem=elem(name, Array[Node]():_*);

scala> elem("A",elem("B"))
res11: scala.xml.Elem = <A><B></B></A>
```

Comment: Yeah, I know how to create Nodes directly. The problem is how to align the strings correctly, set the text nodes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that is close to correct using string concatenation and `XML.loadString`:

```
def spansToXML(text: String, spans: Seq[(Int, Int, Elem)]): Node = {
  // arrange items so that at each offset:
  //   closing tags sort before opening tags
  //   with two opening tags, the one with the later closing tag sorts first
  //   with two closing tags, the one with the later opening tag sorts first
  val items = Buffer[(Int, Int, Int, String)]()
  for ((begin, end, elem) <- spans) {
    val elemStr = elem.toString
    val splitIndex = elemStr.indexOf('>') + 1
    val beginTag = elemStr.substring(0, splitIndex)
    val endTag = elemStr.substring(splitIndex)
    items += ((begin, +1, -end, beginTag))
    items += ((end, -1, -begin, endTag))
  }
  // group tags to be inserted by index
  val inserts = Map[Int, Buffer[String]]()
  for ((index, _, _, tag) <- items.sorted) {
    inserts.getOrElseUpdate(index, Buffer[String]()) += tag
  }
  // put tags and characters into a buffer
  val result = Buffer[String]()
  for (i <- 0 until text.size + 1) {
    for (tags <- inserts.get(i); tag <- tags) {
      result += tag
    }
    result += text.slice(i, i + 1)
  }
  // create XML from the string buffer
  XML.loadString(result.mkString)
}
```

This passes both of the first two test cases, but fails on the third.